# Sourcetree discovers GitHub acc and repos, but cannot clone

Tags: git, proxy, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm trying to set up Sourcetree behind a corporate proxy. I have gotten it to work mostly: I added the public SSH key to GitHub, the private key to Sourcetree, and I added my remote GitHub Account to Sourcetree. It discovers all my repos nicely:

[image]

However, when I choose one and want to clone, it says it's unable to connect/is invalid repo:

[image]

In the Network settings for proxy I have "Use default operating system settings."

What am I missing? How can I clone my repos?

Comment: The `host not found` text in the one popup window suggests that there's a typo in a hostname or URL. The visible `git@github.com` part looks correct, so perhaps there's a typo in your `.ssh/config` file. (Or perhaps there's just some invisible character here.)

Comment: @torek there's no typo anywhere, everything is auto-generated from my login info and I manually double-checked and there's no issues at all with typos.

Comment: are you accessing it from the company level network?

Answer (score -1):

The following worked for me. Change this:

```
git@github.com{repo}
```

into an URL:

```
https://{token}@github.com/{repo}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: What token? I'm working with SSH keys, not tokens.

Comment: personal token from github

Comment: Again, I'm using SSH keys. I don't think if you use SSH keys you also need tokens.

Comment: Is it solved yet?